# Create Dataset (ADS) to build predictve model for servey data

Tags: dataset, predictive-modeling

I have collected labeled survey data spanning 8 months in 2023, capturing satisfaction levels ranging from "very satisfied" to "very dissatisfied."

My objective is to develop a predictive model utilizing telecom data for all customers, even those lacking survey data. I aim to utilize their satisfaction rating for a specific month in order to construct the Analytical Data Set (ADS).

However, a challenge arises as the satisfaction information pertains only to that particular month.

For instance:

Customer_1 January: Dissatisfied August: Satisfied

I'm seeking guidance on how to effectively generate an Analytical Data Set (ADS) with telecom features to facilitate the creation of this predictive model. Are there alternative strategies that can be employed to address this issue?

I greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you.